# Java tabled output to file

Tags: java

I'm interested in a way of outputting some objects to a table like way the objects. Concrete example would  be something like:

```
-------------------------------------------
|  Name      |     foo     |      bar     |
-------------------------------------------
| asdas      | dsfsd       |1233.23       |
| adasdasd   | fsdfs       |3.23          |
| sdasjd     | knsdfsd     |13.23         |
| lkkkj      | dsfsd       |2343.23       |
-------------------------------------------
```

Or  an ms office / open office excel file.(is there an api doc for this type of outputting data in specific editors? like  how to define a table in OpenPffice)?

I'm asking this because I would like to know the best way doing this.
PS: there is no need to deserialise.

Comment: What happens when you google for "Java Excel API" or for "Java Openoffice API"?

Comment: please browse apache poi library.

Comment: @JBNizet I wanted to know what would be a good way of doing it... and maybe find  out about java specific librarys... T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) is a library for creating and manipulating .docx,pptx and excel files.

If you do not feel like using docx4java or it does not fit your needs you can try these

- [Apache Poi](http://www.openoffice.org/api/)
- [Open Office API](http://www.openoffice.org/api/)

Comment: You can also try what @Garret Hall Did.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to export to a comma-separated values which you can open in Excel.

You can use the [data-exporter library](http://code.google.com/p/data-exporter/).